# Can a lambda allow another object to inject an action

Tags: c#, winforms, events, lambda

I want a WinForm to register the `OnLoad` event with another object - something like:

```
 SomeObject.RegisterEvent(action => this.OnLoad += (o,e) => action(o,e));
```

Is this possible? I don't mind creating delegates or expressions for 'helpers' on the 'SomeObject' side to do this, but I'm trying to figure out what my method signature would even look like for the `RegisterEvent(...)`.

Comment: sorry, not really clear what you are trying to achieve.. what architecture are you trying to construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RegisterEvent method would need to look like this:

```
void RegisterEvent(Action<EventHandler> addEventHandler)
{
    addEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        // loaded
    });
}
```

*Usage:*

```
someObject.RegisterEvent(handler => { this.OnLoad += handler; });
```

Comment: this should work ...I'll give it a try - obviously, I was trying to find the forest but couldn't see it for the trees...

Answer (score 0):

```
 SomeObject.RegisterEvent(action => { this.OnLoad += (o,e) => {action(o,e);}; });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have something like that (always a good question, usually things like this are a tell signs of something a bit odd-ish about the design, but doesn't have to be),

I'd say you should look at [The Reactive Extensions (Rx)...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609).
They provide the ease with dealing and firing off your own 'events' more or less like properties or methods (and w/o the typical pain of delegates, add/subscribe or private limitations etc., over simplified a bit).
...and this could look like...

```
someObjectInstance.MyEvent.Subscribe(d=>
{
    // ... your lambda more or less
});
```

...and in the class there is if simplified just one `Subject<MyEventData> _myEvent;` and `_myEvent.OnNext(data)` (goes inside the method you want to rise from) + the property to expose that field (`IObservable<MyEventData> MyEvent {get{return _myEvent;}}`).

which is what you want really.

You can install them from NuGet and use in minutes. Though there is a learning curve for more tricky cases.

Plus you get the benefit of combining events in the future and lot more.

(not 'one of them', just a very good new piece of technology)